# Custom ImageView with drop shadow

Tags: android, overriding, imageview, dropshadow

Okay, I've been reading and searching around, and am now banging my head against the wall trying to figure this out. Here's what I have so far:

```
package com.pockdroid.sandbox;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ShadowImageView extends ImageView {

private Rect mRect;
private Paint mPaint;

public ShadowImageView(Context context)
{
    super(context);
    mRect = new Rect();
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setShadowLayer(2f, 1f, 1f, Color.BLACK);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
{
    Rect r = mRect;
    Paint paint = mPaint;

    canvas.drawRect(r, paint);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int w, int h)
{
    super.onMeasure(w,h);
    int mH, mW;
    mW = getSuggestedMinimumWidth() < getMeasuredWidth()? getMeasuredWidth() : getSuggestedMinimumWidth();
    mH = getSuggestedMinimumHeight() < getMeasuredHeight()? getMeasuredHeight() : getSuggestedMinimumHeight();
    setMeasuredDimension(mW + 5, mH + 5);
}
```

}

The "+5" in the measurements are there as temporary; From what I understand I'll need to do some math to determine the size that the drop shadow adds to the canvas, right?

But when I use this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ShadowImageView sImageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        sImageView = new ShadowImageView(mContext);
        GridView.LayoutParams lp = new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85);
        sImageView.setLayoutParams(lp);

        sImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
        sImageView.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
    } else {
        sImageView = (ShadowImageView) convertView;
    }

    sImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapList.get(position));
    return sImageView;
}
```

in my ImageView, I still get just a normal ImageView when I run the program.

Any thoughts? Thanks.

EDIT: So I spoke with RomainGuy some in the IRC channel, and I have it working now for plain rectangular images with the below code. It still won't draw the shadow directly to my bitmap's transparency though, so I'm still working on that.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
{
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.omen);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setShadowLayer(5.5f, 6.0f, 6.0f, Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.GRAY);
    canvas.drawRect(50, 50, 50 + bmp.getWidth(), 50 + bmp.getHeight(), paint);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 50, 50, null);       
}
```

Comment: "it working now for plain rectangular images" ... so it doesn't work for non-rectangular images, and then I assume it also doesn't work for 9patch-images, correct? Did you meanwhile get it to work? Cause this approach by Romain Guy doesn't work for me in my test yet.

Comment: Hmm, interesting question. I would think you could probably take your View that's using the 9-patch, and wrap it in a FrameLayout, and give the FrameLayout the drop shadow 9-patch background. But yeah, it only works for rectangular images, because there's no way for a 9-patch to follow transparency contours. I unfortunately haven't found a better solution, however, I haven't really tried again since.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Okay, I don't foresee any more answers on this one, so what I ended up going with for now is just a solution for rectangular images. I've used the following NinePatch:
[image]
along with the appropriate padding in XML:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_test"
        android:background="@drawable/drop_shadow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="6px"
        android:paddingTop="4px"
        android:paddingRight="8px"
        android:paddingBottom="9px"
        android:src="@drawable/pic1"
        />
```

to get a fairly good result:
[image]
Not ideal, but it'll do.

Comment: Don't forget to save the png as drop_shadow.9.png.

Comment: Wow, I spent way too much time trying to do this in code. Much more elegant solution!

Comment: What about images that need to adjust the view bounds?

Comment: There's no need to use the draw9patch tool if you make it correctly.

Comment: Sometimes the 9patch won't work if 1 pixel-wide rows are used. For me it only worked as expected when I streched the left and top rows to be 2-3 pixel wide.

Comment: A bit more step by step tutorial can be found here: http://sapandiwakar.in/adding-shadows-to-views-in-android-using-9-patch-image/

Comment: Can you also provide the link to download this 9 patch image? that will be helpful.

Answer (score 107):

This is taken from Romain Guy's presentation at Devoxx, pdf found [here](http://www.devoxx.com/download/attachments/1705921/D8_C_10_09_04.pdf).

```
Paint mShadow = new Paint(); 
// radius=10, y-offset=2, color=black 
mShadow.setShadowLayer(10.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f, 0xFF000000); 
// in onDraw(Canvas) 
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0.0f, 0.0f, mShadow);
```

**NOTES**

1. Don't forget for Honeycomb and above you need to invoke
   `setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, mShadow)`, otherwise you will not see your shadow! (@Dmitriy_Boichenko)
2. `SetShadowLayer` does
   not work with hardware acceleration unfortunately so it greatly
   reduces performances (@Matt Wear) [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749906/android-canvas-setshadowlayer-greatly-decreases-performance) [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7523622/setshadowlayer-causes-slow-draw-time-in-gridview)

Comment: I will definitely try this later! Thanks for the PDF as well, looks like interesting stuff. Is this presentation video available online to watch?

Comment: Don't forget for Honeycomb and above invoke setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, mShadow). If not you will not see your shadow.

Comment: setShadowLayer does not work with hardware acceleration unfortunately.

Comment: you apply a Paint to shapes too, so shadow layer works for them. It won't be applied to inner 'holes' in a shape, however.

Comment: Devoxx link is dead

Comment: @PaulBurke can you please add shadowOffset and shadowRadius param means in setShadowLayer method. The docs are not very clear.

Answer (score 14):

I believe this answer from [UIFuel](http://www.uifuel.com/android-creating-a-drop-shadow-in-xml-layout/)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

     <!-- Drop Shadow Stack -->
     <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="#00CCCCCC" />
        </shape>
    </item>
     <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="#10CCCCCC" />
        </shape>
    </item>
     <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="#20CCCCCC" />
        </shape>
    </item>
     <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="#30CCCCCC" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="#50CCCCCC" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Background -->
    <item>
    <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
        <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 13):

My dirty solution:

```
private static Bitmap getDropShadow3(Bitmap bitmap) {

    if (bitmap==null) return null;
    int think = 6;
    int w = bitmap.getWidth();
    int h = bitmap.getHeight();

    int newW = w - (think);
    int newH = h - (think);

    Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, conf);
    Bitmap sbmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, newW, newH, false);

    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(bmp);

    // Right
    Shader rshader = new LinearGradient(newW, 0, w, 0, Color.GRAY, Color.LTGRAY, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
    paint.setShader(rshader);
    c.drawRect(newW, think, w, newH, paint);

    // Bottom
    Shader bshader = new LinearGradient(0, newH, 0, h, Color.GRAY, Color.LTGRAY, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
    paint.setShader(bshader);
    c.drawRect(think, newH, newW  , h, paint);

    //Corner
    Shader cchader = new LinearGradient(0, newH, 0, h, Color.LTGRAY, Color.LTGRAY, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
    paint.setShader(cchader);
    c.drawRect(newW, newH, w  , h, paint);


    c.drawBitmap(sbmp, 0, 0, null);

    return bmp;
}
```

result:
[image]

Comment: it gives blue shadow always !

Answer (score 9):

Here you are. Set source of ImageView statically in xml or dynamically in code.

Shadow is here white.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <View android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/image"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/image" android:layout_alignTop="@id/image"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/image" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

    <ImageView android:id="@id/image" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="..."
        android:padding="5dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Definitely not what I'm looking for. I'm wanting an actual rendered drop shadow that fades to transparent; that will just give me a white box behind my image.

Comment: @kcoppock - there's no need to downvote this answer - it wasn't really that bad.

Answer (score 4):

I manage to apply gradient border using this code..

```
public static Bitmap drawShadow(Bitmap bitmap, int leftRightThk, int bottomThk, int padTop) {
    int w = bitmap.getWidth();
    int h = bitmap.getHeight();
    
    int newW = w - (leftRightThk * 2);
    int newH = h - (bottomThk + padTop);
    
    Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, conf);
    Bitmap sbmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, newW, newH, false);
    
    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(bmp);
            
    // Left
    int leftMargin = (leftRightThk + 7)/2;
    Shader lshader = new LinearGradient(0, 0, leftMargin, 0, Color.TRANSPARENT, Color.BLACK, TileMode.CLAMP);
    paint.setShader(lshader);
    c.drawRect(0, padTop, leftMargin, newH, paint); 
    
    // Right
    Shader rshader = new LinearGradient(w - leftMargin, 0, w, 0, Color.BLACK, Color.TRANSPARENT, TileMode.CLAMP);
    paint.setShader(rshader);
    c.drawRect(newW, padTop, w, newH, paint);
    
    // Bottom
    Shader bshader = new LinearGradient(0, newH, 0, bitmap.getHeight(), Color.BLACK, Color.TRANSPARENT, TileMode.CLAMP);
    paint.setShader(bshader);
    c.drawRect(leftMargin -3, newH, newW + leftMargin + 3, bitmap.getHeight(), paint);
    c.drawBitmap(sbmp, leftRightThk, 0, null);
    
    return bmp;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me ...

```
public class ShadowImage extends Drawable {

Bitmap bm;

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {

    Paint mShadow = new Paint();
    Rect rect = new Rect(0,0,bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight());

    mShadow.setAntiAlias(true);
    mShadow.setShadowLayer(5.5f, 4.0f, 4.0f, Color.BLACK);

    canvas.drawRect(rect, mShadow);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bm, 0.0f, 0.0f, null);

}

public ShadowImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
    super();
    this.bm = bitmap;
} ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here the Implementation of [Paul Burke](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3723654/1885518)s answer:

```
public class ShadowImageView extends ImageView {

    public ShadowImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public ShadowImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ShadowImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    private Paint createShadow() {
        Paint mShadow = new Paint();

        float radius = 10.0f;
        float xOffset = 0.0f;
        float yOffset = 2.0f;

        // color=black
        int color = 0xFF000000;
        mShadow.setShadowLayer(radius, xOffset, yOffset, color);


        return mShadow;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Paint mShadow = createShadow();
        Drawable d = getDrawable();
        if (d != null){
            setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, mShadow);
            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) getDrawable()).getBitmap();
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0.0f, 0.0f, mShadow);
        } else {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
        }

    };

}
```

TODO:
execute `setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, mShadow);` only if API Level is > 10

Comment: Apologies, the infinite loop was called by a Realm class

Comment: I cant until the question is edited. Just make any small change, let me know and then I will upvote again.

Answer (score 0):

I've built upon the answer above - https://stackoverflow.com/a/11155031/2060486 - to create a shadow around ALL sides..

```
 private static final int GRAY_COLOR_FOR_SHADE = Color.argb(50, 79, 79, 79);

// this method takes a bitmap and draws around it 4 rectangles with gradient to create a
// shadow effect.
public static Bitmap addShadowToBitmap(Bitmap origBitmap) {
    int shadowThickness = 13; // can be adjusted as needed
    int bmpOriginalWidth = origBitmap.getWidth();
    int bmpOriginalHeight = origBitmap.getHeight();
    int bigW = bmpOriginalWidth + shadowThickness * 2; // getting dimensions for a bigger bitmap with margins
    int bigH = bmpOriginalHeight + shadowThickness * 2;
    Bitmap containerBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bigW, bigH, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Bitmap copyOfOrigBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(origBitmap, bmpOriginalWidth, bmpOriginalHeight, false);
    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(containerBitmap); // drawing the shades on the bigger bitmap
    //right shade - direction of gradient is positive x (width)
    Shader rightShader = new LinearGradient(bmpOriginalWidth, 0, bigW, 0, GRAY_COLOR_FOR_SHADE,
            Color.TRANSPARENT, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
    paint.setShader(rightShader);
    canvas.drawRect(bigW - shadowThickness, shadowThickness, bigW, bigH - shadowThickness, paint);
    //bottom shade - direction is positive y (height)
    Shader bottomShader = new LinearGradient(0, bmpOriginalHeight, 0, bigH, GRAY_COLOR_FOR_SHADE,
            Color.TRANSPARENT, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
    paint.setShader(bottomShader);
    canvas.drawRect(shadowThickness, bigH - shadowThickness, bigW - shadowThickness, bigH, paint);
    //left shade - direction is negative x
    Shader leftShader = new LinearGradient(shadowThickness, 0, 0, 0, GRAY_COLOR_FOR_SHADE,
            Color.TRANSPARENT, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
    paint.setShader(leftShader);
    canvas.drawRect(0, shadowThickness, shadowThickness, bigH - shadowThickness, paint);
    //top shade - direction is negative y
    Shader topShader = new LinearGradient(0, shadowThickness, 0, 0, GRAY_COLOR_FOR_SHADE,
            Color.TRANSPARENT, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
    paint.setShader(topShader);
    canvas.drawRect(shadowThickness, 0, bigW - shadowThickness, shadowThickness, paint);
    // starting to draw bitmap not from 0,0 to get margins for shade rectangles
    canvas.drawBitmap(copyOfOrigBitmap, shadowThickness, shadowThickness, null);
    return containerBitmap;
}
```

Change the color in the const as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

Use this class to draw shadow on bitmaps

```
public class ShadowGenerator {

    // Percent of actual icon size
    private static final float HALF_DISTANCE = 0.5f;
    public static final float BLUR_FACTOR = 0.5f/48;

    // Percent of actual icon size
    private static final float KEY_SHADOW_DISTANCE = 1f/48;
    public static final int KEY_SHADOW_ALPHA = 61;

    public static final int AMBIENT_SHADOW_ALPHA = 30;

    private static final Object LOCK = new Object();
    // Singleton object guarded by {@link #LOCK}
    private static ShadowGenerator sShadowGenerator;

    private  int mIconSize;

    private final Canvas mCanvas;
    private final Paint mBlurPaint;
    private final Paint mDrawPaint;
    private final Context mContext;

    private ShadowGenerator(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mIconSize = Utils.convertDpToPixel(context,63);
        mCanvas = new Canvas();
        mBlurPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG);
        mBlurPaint.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(mIconSize * BLUR_FACTOR, Blur.NORMAL));
        mDrawPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG);
    }

    public synchronized Bitmap recreateIcon(Bitmap icon) {
        mIconSize = Utils.convertDpToPixel(mContext,3)+icon.getWidth();
        int[] offset = new int[2];
        Bitmap shadow = icon.extractAlpha(mBlurPaint, offset);
        Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(mIconSize, mIconSize, Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas.setBitmap(result);

        // Draw ambient shadow
        mDrawPaint.setAlpha(AMBIENT_SHADOW_ALPHA);
        mCanvas.drawBitmap(shadow, offset[0], offset[1], mDrawPaint);

        // Draw key shadow
        mDrawPaint.setAlpha(KEY_SHADOW_ALPHA);
        mCanvas.drawBitmap(shadow, offset[0], offset[1] + KEY_SHADOW_DISTANCE * mIconSize, mDrawPaint);

        // Draw the icon
        mDrawPaint.setAlpha(255);
        mCanvas.drawBitmap(icon, 0, 0, mDrawPaint);

        mCanvas.setBitmap(null);
        return result;
    }



    public static ShadowGenerator getInstance(Context context) {

        synchronized (LOCK) {
            if (sShadowGenerator == null) {
                sShadowGenerator = new ShadowGenerator(context);
            }
        }
        return sShadowGenerator;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to use the custom imageView, I suggest you use [this one](https://github.com/zhaozhentao/MaterialImageView/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/zzt/library/MaterialImageView.java)

View look perfect and dont't use any nine path image

[image]