# Duplicating title bar shadow

Tags: android

How would I go about implementing a shadow like the one you see under the title bar?  I know this can be done (see for example the app "Andlytics", where this effect shows on the bottom as well).

[image]

My best guess is that it's a banner image used as the background for the layout. But maybe there is a better way?

Comment: Can you show a image of this effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked through the images in the SDK's data/res folder and I found what is probably being used: `title_bar_shadow.9.png` . Errr, can't attach it here, but you should be able to find it in your `android-sdk-location/platforms/android-N/data/res/drawable-hdpi/` folder.

Comment: Intersting ill check it out in a few hours

Comment: All answers are valid but this is the one I've gone with

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing it is probably achieved by using a 9-patch with a gradient on the top edge and corners as the layout background. I don't know of any better way, but this should be pretty simple to implement.

Comment: Hmm ok I was hoping for a comfiguratio or method but this sg ould be ok. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this question: [Custom ImageView with drop shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693234/custom-imageview-with-drop-shadow)

Comment: Intresting, ill give it a try tommorow and make it work on a layout

Answer (score 1):

Or we could use a gradient - and Android seems to be going that way.
In later versions of the platform SDK code, the title bar image is replaced by action_bar_divider.xml.

The divide is nothing but:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<gradient
    android:startColor="#ffe1e2e4"
    android:endColor="#ff95979a"
    android:angle="270" />
</shape>
```

You can use it in an image view just below your title bar.