# How to get boxes with shadow on an Android application UI?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

I'm going to develop a UI something like the image below, but I don't know how can I get boxes likes this with shadows behind ?

How can I achieve this ? I'm wondering if TableLayout may be a good tool for this but I don't know where to start and how to add shadows. Any helps appreciated.

[image]

Comment: This might serve as a starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14930984/extending-android-view-class-to-add-a-dropshadow

Comment: @LittleChild ok thanks, I'm reading ... hope it helps

Comment: @LittleChild the problem is I don't know how to create boxes,  shadows is my secondary problem.

Comment: You need to create shapes. Look here: http://mobileappdev.learningtree.com/2012/08/01/customising-buttons-with-android-shape-drawables/ This will show you how to create shapes using XML.

Comment: @LittleChild really thanks ... how can i make it resizable in portrait and landscape modes ?

Comment: You can define different layouts for portrait and landscape modes.
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use 9-patched images. [Here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) you can find a good tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this blog spot, "Definitely the most helpful post on this subject, 10x." :
 http://www.uifuel.com/android-creating-a-drop-shadow-in-xml-layout/