# Add shadow on right and bottom side of the layout

Tags: android, android-layout, drawable, android-drawable

I want to add a light shadow on the right and bottom side of the layout.I tried using `android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"` but it adds a thick shadow on all four sides of the layout.What drawable i need to create and set as background?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame">
       <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/g"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/logo_icon"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:clickable="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14930984/extending-android-view-class-to-add-a-dropshadow - Refer this link

Comment: I think you need to go for custom shadow effect

Comment: This is what I referred and it worked .

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005714/how-to-show-shadow-around-the-linearlayout-in-android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android LinearLayout : Add border with shadow around a linearLayout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095223/android-linearlayout-add-border-with-shadow-around-a-linearlayout)

Comment: Yes Nine Patch would work 
Do search for that , Here is the example
http://stackoverflow.com/a/31722183/3303075

Answer (score 18):

I think this may solve your problem

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item>
            <shape>
                <padding android:bottom="2dp" android:left="0dp" android:right="2dp"
                         android:top="0dp"/>
                <solid android:color="#00CCCCCC"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape>
                <padding android:bottom="2dp" android:left="0dp" android:right="2dp"
                         android:top="0dp"/>
                <solid android:color="#10CCCCCC"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape>
                <padding android:bottom="2dp" android:left="0dp" android:right="2dp"
                         android:top="0dp"/>
                <solid android:color="#20CCCCCC"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape>
                <padding android:bottom="2dp" android:left="0dp" android:right="2dp"
                         android:top="0dp"/>
                <solid android:color="#30CCCCCC"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape>
                <padding android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:top="1dp"/>
                <solid android:color="#50CCCCCC"/>
            </shape>
        </item>

        <!-- Background -->
        <item>
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
                <corners android:radius="3dp"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
```

Then apply it to an XML layout as a background `LinearLayout` `android:background="@drawable/drawable_name"`

Answer (score 1):

This is what I referred and it worked.

** 1.Add a plain LinearLayout with grey color, over which add your actual layout, with margin at bottom and right equal to 1 or 2 dp

2.Have a 9-patch image with a shadow and set it as the background to your Linear layout**

[Other solutions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005714/how-to-show-shadow-around-the-linearlayout-in-android)

Comment: Point 1 is nice idea !

Answer (score -4):

Just put `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` into your Manifest Application.