# How do I apply drop Shadow right and bottom of transparent view in Android?

Tags: android, xml, view

I want to apply **drop shadow right and bottom** on view (TextView/LinearLayout) with **transparent background**. 
I have draw shadow using Layer-list as said in this link:

[Add shadow on right and bottom side of the layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30068322/add-shadow-on-right-and-bottom-side-of-the-layout)

but it is not giving me desired transparency.
can any one help me out?

Thanks

Comment: Consider this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406524/how-to-set-shadow-to-a-view-in-android/27532712#27532712

Comment: Check this link. Hope It may help you:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693234/custom-imageview-with-drop-shadow?rq=1

Comment: actually I am creating bitmap combination of outline border and gradient inside, so thinking of making gradient left and bottom and append to bitmap.