# How to apply shadow to ImageView?

Tags: android, android-imageview, textview, shadow

I want to apply shadow to the `ImageView`. When I'm applying shadow to a `TextView` I'm getting it but same it's not getting to `ImageView`. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I think you are looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693234/custom-imageview-with-drop-shadow I hope this should help you.

Comment: I may be wrong, but what you are using is a "text shadow" on `TextView`. This is fine. What you asking for is a "box shadow" on `ImageView`. I don't believe this exists. You'd need to build a custom background, that looked like a shadow to achieve this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom ImageView with drop shadow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693234/custom-imageview-with-drop-shadow)

Comment: `android:elevation="2dp"` is good enough sometimes

Comment: Seems like `android:elevation` works only if you have `android:background` defined. Without defining both I get no shadow at all.

Answer (score 8):

We can also use [CardView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html) which provides a rounded corner background and shadow. To use that you need to add the [v7 CardView library](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-cardview) as a dependency to the project in the build.gradle like below.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
    -------
}
```

> Note: Change `23.0.1` in the above line with the respected version.

So I surrounded the `ImageView` with `CardView` to make shadow like below.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dish_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

It'll add a shadow around the image.

> Note: I don't know whether it is a good workaround. I am a beginner. I
>   tried to implement the `CardView` which gives an idea to implement
>   the same for this. If it is not good please update me with the reason.

Comment: How is `card_view` declared?

Comment: ...same as how the `app` xmlns is usually declared.

Comment: What about circle ImageView?

Comment: @user924 I'm seeing this answer after a long time :-). Cardview internally using elevation for higher end devices. For lower end devices it's using a custom drawing on canvas. So better [refer here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/bc943f7/v7/cardview/src/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.java) in the source for more info. I'll take some time to update the answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is taken from Romain Guy's presentation at Devoxx, pdf found [here](http://www.devoxx.com/download/attachments/1705921/D8_C_10_09_04.pdf).

```
Paint mShadow = new Paint(); 
// radius=10, y-offset=2, color=black 
mShadow.setShadowLayer(10.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f, 0xFF000000); 
// in onDraw(Canvas) 
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0.0f, 0.0f, mShadow);
```

Hope this helps.

**NOTES**

Don't forget for Honeycomb and above you need to invoke `setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, mShadow)`, otherwise you will not see your shadow! (@Dmitriy_Boichenko)

`SetShadowLayer` does not work with hardware acceleration unfortunately so it greatly reduces performances (@Matt Wear)

Answer Taken from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693234/custom-imageview-with-drop-shadow)

For Api greater than 21.
You can try in xml in imageview or Button : [Read here at developer site](http://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html)

```
android:elevation="5dp"
```

Comment: `android:elevation` does not appear to work on ImageView

Comment: Elevation was added in api 21. You may be using lower version. Use card layout for lower api version.

Comment: I'm using API 24. Elevation seems to work fine on most things, but not on ImageView.

Comment: What is `bitmap`?

Comment: Your imageview will have match parent height and width, try giving margin or padding. As elevation will be hidden behind the other layout.

Comment: get bitmap from image. Call this after image is completly loaded or you will get null.

    Bitmap bm=((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

Answer (score 3):

Create a file shadow_rect.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item >
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
            <corners android:radius="0dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:right="1dp"  android:bottom="2dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
            <corners android:radius="1dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

And the use this as **android:background="@drawable/shadow_rect** within your Imageview.

Answer (score 2):

**ImageView**

```
  <ImageView
     ......
  android:elevation="2dp"
  android:background="@drawable/myrect"/>
```

The background drawable is defined as a rectangle with rounded corners:

```
<!-- res/drawable/myrect.xml -->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#42000000" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: did you try to understand what OP is asking ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a layer list drawable and put your two items (drawables) in it for an image and your shadow.

Your shadow item's position & content might change according to where you want to apply the shadow (top, left, right, both right & left etc) and style of your shadow.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the proprety `outlineSpotShadowColor`

to put the shadow to **true** try `setOutlineSpotShadowColor` with `@color/black` and increase the `elevation` to 12dp

to put the shadow to **false** `setOutlineSpotShadowColor` with `@android:color/transparent` and decrease the `elevation`

Answer (score 0):

`CardView` is the perfect solution for this but if you don't want to use then you can use the XML layer. Here I am applying shadow 4th side of the image.

*drawable/bg_shadow.xml:* If you need more width border then you can change/remove the value of `android:right android:left android:top android:bottom`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item >
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#e5e5e5" />
            <corners android:radius="4dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:right=".5dp" android:left=".5dp" android:top=".5dp" android:bottom=".5dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
            <corners android:radius="4dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

On the layout, you have to use it as a background, and `android:elevation` will give a light style. To avoid crop you can use `android:layout_margin`.

```
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_shadow"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_image" />
```