# How to create shadow for views on google map?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have an imageView on top a map fragment and I want to create shadow around it to look outstanding but as you may know shadows in android need a background to be applied on while map is not a suitable background. So is there any way to achieve this shadow?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping for API 21+, use elevation property

Comment: `"but as you may know shadows in android need a background"` what do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean if a view doesn't have a background, then the elevation wouldn't show shadow.

Answer (score 0):

You can create CardView as wrapper for image view. Like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32977401).

Or create a drawable and set to your image view as `android:background`. Like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38346052).

Or check [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it like this

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/imgWrapper"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                    card_view:cardElevation="5dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/image"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:src="@drawable/your_drawable" />
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Just place your imageView inside the card with having elevations like above.

Comment: I dont't know how your are doing but the shadow should work both by using drawable or cardview whether its a map or any other layout as background.