# Possible bug with shadow layer?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-canvas, draw

I'm trying to achieve shadow around an oval using this code:

```
shadow = new Paint();
    shadow.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    shadow.setShadowLayer(10, 0, 0, Color.YELLOW);
```

and the draw function goes like this:

```
c.drawOval(ovalRect, shadow);
super.draw(c); //Draws bitmap
```

So first of all it draw oval with the paint containing the shadow, and then on top of it draws bitmap with transparancy (Bitmap doesn't have any paint).

I get the following outcome:
[image: screenshot]
As you can see the shadow isn't spread along the oval, but it's getting cut out, what could cause this behavior?

Comment: maybe it's a padding issue ?

Comment: That looks like to if you the thing where the 3 chip is on it(label, panel, idk) is to small. The shadow dosent fit on that so you have to make the panel, label or what you use bigger so the shadow fits in

Comment: I would understand it, if the shadow was cut out only by the neighboring buttons, however, here we can see that it is cut out from the top as well.

Comment: I have a similar result when using textview with shadows. I fix it by adding a padding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this maybe by changing the radius :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <!-- Drop Shadow Stack -->
    <item>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="12dp" />

            <padding
                android:bottom="1dp"
                android:left="1dp"
                android:right="1dp"
                android:top="1dp" />

            <solid android:color="#00CCCCCC" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="12dp" />

            <padding
                android:bottom="1dp"
                android:left="1dp"
                android:right="1dp"
                android:top="1dp" />

            <solid android:color="#10CCCCCC" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="12dp" />

            <padding
                android:bottom="1dp"
                android:left="1dp"
                android:right="1dp"
                android:top="1dp" />

            <solid android:color="#20CCCCCC" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="12dp" />

            <padding
                android:bottom="1dp"
                android:left="1dp"
                android:right="1dp"
                android:top="1dp" />

            <solid android:color="#30CCCCCC" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="12dp" />

            <padding
                android:bottom="1dp"
                android:left="1dp"
                android:right="1dp"
                android:top="1dp" />

            <solid android:color="#50CCCCCC" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Background -->
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />

            <corners android:radius="12dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: I'm using custom view class, this won't help

Comment: Do you use an ImageView ? or just Paint ?

Comment: I'm subclassing view and using canvas.drawBitmap() for the image and canvas.drawOval() for the oval with the shadow

Comment: Maybe look at other posts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17410195/setshadowlayer-android-api-differences

Comment: Thanks the last link did the job!

Answer (score 0):

Late to the game, but still might help someone:

Try to set `android:clipChildren="false"` to the parent ViewGroup.

Depending on your layout you also might need to additionally add a bit of padding to the **parent** and set `android:clipToPadding="false"` on that parent.

That usually allows the children (and thus also their shadows) to draw outside of their boundaries.