# Application crashing only in 4.4.2 when using setShadowLayer()

Tags: android

I am using `textview.setShadowLayer(60,0,0, 0xFF303030);` inside the custom adapter of my list view. My application is running properly in all the other phones at than 4.4.2 version.

At first I was unable to find what was the real cause of the problem. Then I noticed that whenever I am commenting the above line, my application is running fine in 4.4.2.

Please help me to find a solution to use the above code in all the versions or suggest any alternative for the above code.

Comment: why are you trying to use shadow layer??

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin: For setting a light background at the back of my text view. I got that code from this link: http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/06/set-shadow-of-textview-in-java-code.html

Comment: see if this help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17414651/3640637

Comment: When stuff crashes, *post a stack trace*.

Comment: @roymathew can you provide an image of the working result

Comment: @PedroHawk: Great solution. It worked.         viewHolder.txtPriceTag.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
viewHolder.txtPriceTag.setShadowLayer(60,0,0, 0xFF303030);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PedroHawk's comment helped me to find a solution to this issue.

This is how I solved the issue:

```
textview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
textview.setShadowLayer(60,0,0, 0xFF303030);
```

While adding the above code directly, caused crashing in 2.3 devices. Then I had to do it like this:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
{
   textview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
}
textview.setShadowLayer(5,0,0, 0xFF303030);
```

The above code made it work properly in all the versions (I have tested with 2.3.3, 4.0.4, 4.4.2).

Comment: I wasted 2 hours on this. Thank you :)