# Path.offset() not working on every device

Tags: android, graphics

I have some problems with android.graphics.path.
I am developing a game. I have some Paths. They don't change there sizes, shapes. I draw them onto a canvas. I move them in every game's frame. So I set an offset: dx

It works fine on many devices:

- Nokia X Dual Sim (Android 4.4.4 Cyanogenmode)(API level 19)
- Samsung Galaxy Duos (GT-S7562)(Android 4.0.4)(API level 15)
- Sony X8 (Android 2.3.7 Cyanogenmode)(API level 10)
- and on some others

But it not works well on some other devices:

- Samsung Galaxy Ace II (Android 4.1.2)(API level 16)
- Nokia X Dual Sim (Nokia X platform 1.2)(Android Studio shows: API level 16)
- and on some others
  I set the offset in my draw method:

  path.offset(dX, 0);

Not working means: it not moves. The system draws it to the original position.
But when it works, it works descent (moves, and it is fast)

I also tried with Matrixes:

```
translateMatrix = new Matrix();
translateMatrix.setTranslate(dX, 0);
path.transform(translateMatrix);
```

The same happened.

I see something on developer site of Android:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html
void offset(float dx, float dy)
Offset the path by (dx,dy), returning true on success.
??? It must have changed, that's why here is an error

It may in connection with the Hardware Accelerated mode:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/HgGVSbSghpk

I support from Api level 9, but I turned Harware Accelerated mode. (It works form API level 14)
The problem also shows up when I turn it off.
I don't see why is it sometimes work over API level 14, and sometimes why not?

It says, hardware accelerated mode supports Path:
http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2011/03/android-30-hardware-acceleration.html

Do you know what is the problem with this? What should I do?

**Something that mixes it up more:**
This works on every device (but works slower - it lags):

```
Canvas temp = new Canvas(bitmap);
path.draw(temp);
originalCanvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, myPaint);
```

So

1. I make a temporary canvas
2. I set it on a bitmap
3. I draw on that canvas (it will be on the bitmap)
4. I draw the bitmap onto the original canvas

Why does it work here?

Please help me how should I make it work.

Comment: Note: I only had the problem on API level 16

Answer (score 1):

I made it work, but not with the offset

I made my own offset function:

1. it saves the last position, and calculates the new one with the
   offset.
2. Then it creates a new Path without using operator new

   calculateNewPoints();
   wallpath.rewind();
   wallpath.moveTo(newPosX, newPosY);
   .
   .
   .
   wallpath.close();

It performs well :)

Answer (score 0):

On API level 16 on manifest add the following attribute to the application
`<application android:hardwareAccelerated="false" ...>`

Answer (score 0):

Indeed there seems to be a bug related to `Path.offset()` on older Android devices.

I have purchased an 8 years old "Samsung Galaxy S3" phone with Android 4.1.2 to test [my word game](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wordsbyfarber) and was surprised to discover, that `Path`s in the app are not filled:

[image: screenshot]

My workaround is shown below, for older Android devices I do not use [Path.offset()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path) anymore, but instead [Canvas.translate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas) and then draw the not offsetted `Path` object:

```
public class LetterTile extends RectF {

    // consider anything older then Android 6.0 Marshmallow as an old device
    public static final boolean TOO_OLD =
        (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M);

    private final Path mPathFill = new Path();
    // mPathFillMoved is same as mPathFill, but offset by left, top
    // it is used on newer devices to paint gradient over all tiles
    private final Path mPathFillMoved = new Path();

    public void draw(Canvas canvas, Paint gradientPaint) {
        if (!TOO_OLD) {
            // the mPathFillMoved only works on newer Android devices
            canvas.drawPath(mPathFillMoved, gradientPaint);
        }

        canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(left, top);

        if (TOO_OLD) {
            // on older Android devices just draw mPathFilled in plain yellow
            canvas.drawPath(mPathFill, gradientPaint);
        }

        canvas.restore();
```