# Text shadow doesn't work on all devices

Tags: android

I have a problem with setting a shadow to TextView as it seems it doesn't work on all devices. I am currently doing it like this:

```
myTextView.setShadowLayer(0.5f, 2.0f, 2.0f, Color.BLACK);
```

It works great on some devices but on some it doesn't appear at all. What could be a problem with this simple code? Thank you.

Comment: switch off hardware acceleration for that view

Answer (score 0):

According to Romain Guy, `setShadowLayer` is only supported when hardware acceleration is on.

so make sure to turn on the acceleration from the application tag in the mainfest

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ...>
```

You may check his answer here: [Romain Guy's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17414651/2296787)

Comment: Thanks :) I have just one short question. How is `setShadowLayer()` only supported when hardware acceleration is on and by setting `myView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)` we disable hardware acceleration?