# It is possible to add IOS Style rear Shadows into Android ImageViews?

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

i'm trying to add these kind of IOS shadows in the back of a imageview on Android:

[image]

I mean the rear shadow in the back of each square. Imagine that each square is an Android IMAGEVIEW, how can i add this shadow in Android?

Comment: You should checkout following post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693234/custom-imageview-with-drop-shadow

Kind regards,  
Bo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below link to your shadow problem

[Custom ImageView with drop shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693234/custom-imageview-with-drop-shadow)

Welcome

Comment: Hi, thanks, but does not exist's a simple way to achieve this?