# Effect shadow in rectangle canvas

Tags: android, canvas, shadow

I have drawn a rectangle with canvas and I wonder if there is any property or way of giving a small shadow.

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Paint pincel1 = new Paint();
    pincel1.setColor(Color.rgb(151, 217, 69));
    RectF rectangle = new RectF(30, 20,200,100);
    canvas.drawRoundRect (rectangle, 6, 6, pincel1);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 38, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693234/custom-imageview-with-drop-shadow) question contained the following code :

```
    Paint mShadow = new Paint();  
// radius=10, y-offset=2, color=black  
mShadow.setShadowLayer(10.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f, 0xFF000000);  
// in onDraw(Canvas)  
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0.0f, 0.0f, mShadow);
```

So customize it a bit to your needs and that will do the trick.

In your case just add `pincel1.setShadowLayer(10.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f, 0xFF000000);` to your code.

Comment: Thanks for answering so quickly,not be as I add this code to my code, i edit the post and add my onDraw() method

Comment: Note that paint.setShadowLayer() does not work with hardware acceleration (see  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html#unsupported)

Comment: @Thierry-DimitriRoy What can you use in it's place instead of this then?  It would seem as though you might have an answer and a new answer to this questions could be helpful for those using hardware acceleration.

Comment: @JaySnayder You have to use PNGs to simulate drop shadows. Note that the L preview add support for drop shadows with hardware acceleration.

Comment: I am able to draw shadow around text but it is very light.how to make shadow layer dark?

Comment: this method is for text only. On some devices it fails

Comment: with   setShader I am applying gradient colors . so shadow also is changing to the gradient color, any solution for that?