# How to highlight imageview in android

Tags: android

Is there a way to programmatically highlight an imageview in android?

I am showing playing cards and I would like to highlight or shade specific cards (imageviews). How can I achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: Would using a shadow work? http://stackoverflow.com/a/4405209/770061

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Checkout [imageView.setColorFilter()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setColorFilter%28int,%20android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode%29)

Answer (score 0):

if you have a custom highlighting outline.

You can put your ImageView inside a LinearLayout. set highlighted image as background of Layout. After doing some margins adjustment, you will have a fine grained custom highlighting.