# Android: Applying shadow to bottom of ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to apply shadow at bootom of ImageView as shown in image below.

Any trick to achieve that in android ??

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom ImageView with drop shadow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693234/custom-imageview-with-drop-shadow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way that I have seen to do this is to create an image that is just a drop shadow and then set that as the background for the container of your image.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693234/custom-imageview-with-drop-shadow) is a really great SO thread about how to do just that.

Answer (score 1):

**No** ,you have to create a image which have shadow as well as border.
so ,after that you have to `set padding` to your image so it's look like this frame.