# How can I give a border to image view in Android?

Tags: android, background, imageview

In my new android app I need to give border to `imageview` by using something like .9.png.

The border size should change with respect to image which I have given to `imageview` and If possible I need to give a background image to `imageview` as I'm going to apply a transparent png image to `imageview`.

Should I create a new custom view for this?

Comment: Check this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693234/custom-imageview-with-drop-shadow

Answer (score 1):

I think you should create a custom view. Do a LinearLayout with the background as the border and have the ImageView centered inside the LinearLayout. Use 9-patch to get a correct stretch and create a content area so that the border is showing (use draw9patch in android SDK/Tools).

Example:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/border">

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Then 9-patch your border (border.9.png in this example). You can have the same stretching as content area.

Comment: k. I will try with this and get back you.

Comment: K I agree with this, I can add border. But I think it won't satisfy the second question. Because  I need a master background image. Is it possible adding one more lenier view for background.

Comment: Either your master background is part of the border image or just make the linearlayout to a relative layout and have to images in it.

Comment: master image is not part of border

Comment: actually my requirement is that. 
I have circle shape coin image(png transparent image ie, no background ) . I need a border for that. and that coin should have a master background. because it is circle shaped.

Comment: If the border is circular it will be hard, I don't know any convenient way to stretch a circular image. However, if the border is square the solution with relativelayout will work fine.