# How to set outer glow effect on ImageView?

Tags: android, android-imageview, glow

I have tried this. but it is not working this on ImageView. but this code is not setting any outer glow on Image.

```
    android:shadowColor="#7ccb16"
    android:shadowDx="0"
    android:shadowDy="0"
    android:shadowRadius="3"
```

guide me how do I do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refered form [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693234/custom-imageview-with-drop-shadow)

using ninepatch tool in android sdk.

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_test"
        android:background="@drawable/drop_shadow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="6px"
        android:paddingTop="4px"
        android:paddingRight="8px"
        android:paddingBottom="9px"
        android:src="@drawable/pic1"
        />
```

I hope this will be useful to you.

Comment: it is a ninepatch image. refer that link friend. ninepatch is interesting tool in android