# Apply glow effect animation on Layout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-animation

In my android application i want to apply glow effect on layout when activity starts. For that i referred [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15584067/how-to-set-outer-glow-effect-on-imageview)  and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693234/custom-imageview-with-drop-shadow) and other links also. But on some links i found that they have used `Canvas` or `OpenGL` but i don't want to use canvas or opengl. I am not getting how to achieve this functionality.Please help me to apply glow effect on layout.

Thank you.

Code : layout.xml (Here i want to apply glow on "lLevel1" layout)

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/lLevel1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_level1"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/rtbLevel1"
        style="@style/CustomRatingBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:isIndicator="true"
        android:numStars="3"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</RelativeLayout>
```