# how to apply Dynamic shadow to imageview in android?

Tags: android, android-imageview

I am facing problem to apply shadow effect to imageview. I tried with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693234/custom-imageview-with-drop-shadow). I need to apply shadow like follwing image. Rectangular is my imageview.

**NOTE :** ***Shadow color is dynamic. Means it may change dynamically.***

[image: Shadow effect in imageview]

I have tried all the examples but they are different from my requirement. stuck with this. Please help me.

Comment: This would help you: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693234/custom-imageview-with-drop-shadow

Good luck

Comment: dude read the question first. he linked it in his question.

Comment: dude it's called 9-patch, not 9 path

Comment: The shadow color is dynamically change. So i cant use 9-patch image / cant apply drawable xml.

Comment: i know, i said it before your edit. @neoh, oops my fault.

Comment: @Hosein yes shadow color is dynamic.

Comment: you mean colors of shadow can change , or something like that!?!

Comment: yes shadow color is change dynamic. It comes from webservice.

Comment: Actually we design themes for app. all parts(colors or etc) are come from webservice. So no need to change in android code.

Comment: @Hosein any idea about this ?

Comment: hmmm... i'm so bad in web service. sorry. but like i said i'm interest in your question and with this explains , interested more. waiting for an answer.