# Google Now dropshadow on view

Tags: android, nine-patch, dropshadow, google-now

I want this awesome dropshadow like the [Google Now Cards](https://imgur.com/gcdwPum). How do I create it? I've been googling around a lot but haven't found any answer to my question. I *have* tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4405209/1329077) answer, but I only get this result:

[image]

And yes, my ninepatch is ending with `.9.png`.

Comment: did you create your nine patch using the draw9patch tool in the SDK tools?

Comment: @Karakuri Yes, yes I did

Answer (score 17, accepted):

So what I did to make this work was to use the `card_background.9.png` nine-patch file from Google Music:

[image: card_background.9.png]

Copy this file to `card_background.9.png` and place in your `res/drawable-xhdpi` folder, you can also do the same for:

[image: card_background.9.png]

in `res/drawable-hdpi` and:

[image: card_background.9.png]

in `res/drawable-mdpi`.

Next come the content view, and grid item layouts.  To get it right you have to be careful about how and where you do the padding and the all important `clipToPadding` property.  First there's the grid layout, this acts as my main content view in the activity, in file `board_grid_layout.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/board_grid_layout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="0dp">    
    <GridView
            android:id="@+id/board_grid_view"
            style="@style/BoardGridView"
            />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the style I used for the BoardGridView in my `styles.xml`, I dimensionalise the constants for supporting tablets/landscaping, but I've hardcoded them here for ease of use:

```
<style name="BoardGridView" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:padding">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:clipToPadding">false</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">top|left</item>
    <item name="android:smoothScrollbar">true</item>
    <item name="android:cacheColorHint">#00000000</item>
    <item name="android:fastScrollEnabled">true</item>
    <item name="android:horizontalSpacing">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:verticalSpacing">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:numColumns">3</item>
    <item name="android:stretchMode">columnWidth</item>
    <item name="android:scrollbarStyle">outsideOverlay</item>
</style>
```

Then there's the grid item layout with the card background.  Here's my layout file `board_grid_item.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/grid_item"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:background="@drawable/card_background"
        >

        <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/grid_item_thread_image_wrap"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                >

            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/grid_item_thread_thumb"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:contentDescription="Thread thumbnail"
                    />
            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/grid_item_country_flag"
                    android:layout_width="18dp"
                    android:layout_height="11dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:contentDescription="Thread country flag"
                    />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="84dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/grid_item_thread_subject"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                    android:paddingRight="8dp"
                    android:textColor="#444"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/grid_item_thread_info"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                    android:paddingRight="8dp"
                    android:textColor="#aaa"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:maxLines="3"
                    />

        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now to hook this together you need a cursor loader and adapter, but that's outside the scope of the question.  This layout should let you make a card-view like Google Music.  Here's the resulting screenshot of the above nine-patch image and xml applied on my Samsung Galaxy S3 in portrait mode:

[image]

Comment: Awesome, gonna try this when I come home. Thanks!

Comment: do you have an image for xxhdpi?

Comment: I don't have an xxhdpi image, but you should be able to get one from the google music APK.  Just download and unzip it.

Comment: FYI, I've just downloaded the Google Music APK and they do NOT use a XXHDPI version of `card_bg_play.9.png`