# Android - Adding shadow to imageview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, nine-patch

I was following the accepted answer of this question: [Custom ImageView with drop shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693234/custom-imageview-with-drop-shadow) to add a shadow to my simple app's image view. I am reusing the exact the same drawable 9-patch image from the answer, and here is my code:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photo"
        android:background="@drawable/imageview_shadow"
        android:paddingLeft="6px"
        android:paddingTop="4px"
        android:paddingRight="8px"
        android:paddingBottom="9px"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/test_img" />
```

It looks good on ADT preview 720P screens, but when I install it to my Nexus 5 which has 1080P resolution, it became like this:

[image]

Which looks pretty bad. I wasn't aware of 9-patch images could behave differently under different screen resolutions. So what could be the issue the shadow is not showing correctly?

Thank you

Comment: It's treated the whole 9-patch including the 1 pixel border as a your image. Use drawable.getBitmap() to get just the image.

Comment: @SoundConceptions can you please provide some more detail on how should I fix this? Thank you!

Comment: Did you forget to save the image as drop_shadow.9.png?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following line will take the whole .png file, including it's 1 pixel border and use it as a bitmap.

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.myNinePatchDrawable);
```

Try replacing this with the following to first extract the image from the NinePatch:

```
NinePatch myNinePatch = (NinePatch)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.myNinePatchDrawable);
Bitmap bmp = myNinePatch.getBitmap();
```