# How to make relative layout with box shadow

Tags: java, android

[image]

How do i make the relative layout look like the image

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693234/custom-imageview-with-drop-shadow

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are two ways to create shadow:

1. If sdk version is lower than 5.0...

   A.  You can also use android drawable image

   ```
   android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
   ```

   B. Use below `shadow_round.xml` to make a drawable background for shadow of view. `android:background="@drawable/shadow_round`

   ```
    <!-- Drop Shadow Stack -->
    <item>
       <shape>
           <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="2dp" android:left="1dp" />
           <corners android:radius="10dp" />
           <solid android:color="#00CCCCCC" />
       </shape>
   </item>
   <item>
       <shape>
           <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="2dp" android:left="1dp" />
           <corners android:radius="10dp" />
           <solid android:color="#10CCCCCC" />
       </shape>
   </item>
   <item>
       <shape>
           <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="2dp" android:left="1dp" />
           <corners android:radius="10dp" />
           <solid android:color="#20CCCCCC" />
       </shape>
   </item>
    <item>
       <shape>
           <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="2dp" android:left="1dp" />
           <corners android:radius="10dp" />
           <solid android:color="#30CCCCCC" />
       </shape>
   </item>
   <item>
       <shape>
           <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="2dp" android:left="1dp" />
           <corners android:radius="10dp" />
           <solid android:color="#50CCCCCC" />
       </shape>
   </item> 

   <!-- Background -->
   <item>
   <shape>
       <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
       <corners android:radius="10dp" />
   </shape>
   </item>
   ```
2. If you are using SDK 5.0 or greater then use the view's **elevation** property.

   ```
   android:elevation="2dp"
   ```

Comment: Using A: This results in a weird flicker every couple of seconds, at least on 5.1 devices. The flicker goes away if you copy the resources from the SDK directly in to your app's res dir. No idea why.

Comment: We've found that B is hideously slow on older, down version Android phones.

Answer (score 4):

simple add elevation property in your relative layout. or
create xml in drowable folder and call as a background

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

       <shape  
             xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:shape="rectangle">
       <solid android:color="#ddd" />
       <stroke
           android:width="5dp"
           android:color="#b8b9b9" />
       <corners
           android:radius="3dp" />
       </shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:- radius.xml

:- this xml add in drawable folder in and relative layout in background in set

```
android:background="@drawable/radius"

<shape android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#b8b9b9"/>
    <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="3dp" android:bottomRightRadius="3dp" android:topLeftRadius="3dp" android:topRightRadius="3dp"/>
</shape>
```