# Resizing an image to fit on a imageview

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I am developing an application in which I need to fit an Bitmap into Imageview with specific dimensions(let's suppose 350dpx50dp - height*width).

I wanted to do something similar like this: http://gyazo.com/d739d03684e46411feb58d66acea1002

I have looked here for solutions. I found this code for scale the bitmap and fit it into imageview, but the problem is that imageview becomes greater when I add the bitmap into him:

```
private void scaleImage(Bitmap bitmap, ImageView view)
{
    // Get current dimensions AND the desired bounding box
    int width = bitmap.getWidth();
    int height = bitmap.getHeight();
    int bounding = dpToPx(350);

    // Determine how much to scale: the dimension requiring less scaling is
    // closer to the its side. This way the image always stays inside your
    // bounding box AND either x/y axis touches it.
    float xScale = ((float) bounding) / width;
    float yScale = ((float) bounding) / height;
    float scale = (xScale <= yScale) ? xScale : yScale;

    // Create a matrix for the scaling and add the scaling data
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postScale(scale, scale);

    // Create a new bitmap and convert it to a format understood by the ImageView
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);

    // Apply the scaled bitmap
    view.setImageBitmap(scaledBitmap);
}
```

Using this code I can get this : http://gyazo.com/e9871db2130ac33668156fc0cf773594

But that's not what I wanted, I want to keep the dimensions of imageview and add the bitmap into imageview without modifying the dimensions of imageview and occupying all the imageview's surface. Like the first image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just add `android:scaleType="fitXY"` to your `ImageView` in xml?

Comment: I tried it. I get the same result: http://gyazo.com/e9871db2130ac33668156fc0cf773594

Comment: Then definitely more info is needed to help

Comment: What kind of information do you need? I could not publish images neither more links due to my reputation xD

Comment: I will show you the xml of the ImageView: http://gyazo.com/c34327780b9115c2c3eafe378cb8c4d1                                I have 6 imageviews: http://gyazo.com/8a53975b4bf9746bb28eb090e5cd61a3                            All of them have the same xml. When I execute a simple code like that(example of one ImageView): http://gyazo.com/320947b4e2d81ddf72541a8e1f105740                         I get this: http://gyazo.com/b40272839f8a095c61289fdfbbdff1a4

Comment: Well definitely the problem is not in scaling the image. I don't think you have to do it manually, the `scaleType` does the same thing. Most probably the problem is in the the layout, you set `ImageView` to wrap and weight it.

Comment: Well, here is the whole code in xml: http://pastebin.com/KvtKDDzL               And the design:                      http://gyazo.com/bf8a863df2e9dd516017880be394193f

Comment: how is your `style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"` defined? Most probably there is some padding defined either in the style or in the 9 patch background.

Comment: From what I've found on the Internet, seems to have padding. Do you know any way to do what I intend to do? Thanks anyway.

Comment: Just provide style without padding :)

Comment: I'm quite newbie in android. How can I define style?

Comment: You should read the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html). Since you probably want to just have frame around your image, remove the `style` parameter from your `ImageView` and add this `android:background="@android:drawable/picture_frame"` This is very simple frame but looks good

Comment: You are right, it seems a better way. But I have executed the code and the same thing keeps happening: http://gyazo.com/50559bb307995869ac431e652629e31e.                                    XML of ImageView: http://gyazo.com/159c573a003946038085dcbd729fdb06

Comment: If I understand correctly you only want to get rid of the bit padding between the image and the shadow?

Comment: Not exactly. I have this Imageview with specific dimension: http://gyazo.com/eb4c7c370de24a7f6c93000c10a281b2                               And I have an image, I want to fit the image into the specific dimension of ImageView, without resizing the ImageView.

Comment: so you want to stretch the image? Try `android:scaleType="fitXY"`. Or you want to crop it to fill the image with `android:scaleType="cropCenter"`?

Comment: I would scale the image to fit the dimensions of the ImageView. I will try what you said.

Comment: With 'android:scaleType="fitXY"' looks great! http://gyazo.com/7deb2c326eb6eab9c4e71af927cd08fb                                     Do you know how I could get rid of the whites of the imageview?

Comment: The background is created by 9 patch image, you should be able to edit it or fing another one

Comment: I'm supposed to let the user choose an image. So if he has one similar like this one, how should I proceed to avoid that white background? Thank you, anyway!

Comment: check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693234/custom-imageview-with-drop-shadow)