# Add shadows at the bottom of image

Tags: android, imageview, shadow

How can I add a shadow over the image (right at the bottom) in order to have the title to be clearly visible. 
See the image below.

[image]

Comment: I think what you are looking for is a gradient mask at the bottom

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693234/custom-imageview-with-drop-shadow

Comment: Amazing post. Thank you guys

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I wrote an application, which has the same effect. What I did is, I created a **FrameLayout** which has the **ImageView** and another **View** which has the same height of the ImageView. Then I add a transparent gradient background to the **View**.

**Example:**

**Layout file:**

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient" />

</FrameLayout>
```

**drawable/gradient.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:endColor="#00ffffff"
        android:startColor="#aa000000"
        android:centerColor="#00ffffff" />
</shape>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a png image with the gradient color and alpha, put it just at the bottom of the banner image. And your name text is upon the image.

Comment: The gradient effects on each banner is familiar.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Drawable file  gradient.xml

```
<gradient
    android:angle="90"
    android:endColor="#00ffffff"
    android:startColor="#aa000000"
    android:centerColor="#00ffffff" />
```

Use ImageView as shown below

```
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:foreground="@drawable/gradient">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="240dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"/>
        </FrameLayout>
```