# How to tint image partially android image view

Tags: java, android, android-studio, imageview

[image: i wanna tint my image same like that only a little bit from bottom]

I have not provided any code cause i have no idea how to implement this. I want to partially  tint my image view in android java  with another color at the bottom  like the on the picture.    Please  help.

Comment: This is similar question to this
[https://stackoverflow.com/q/31959829/11984583](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31959829/11984583)
check this for

Comment: Its deep than what meets the eye, if you try to implement it

Answer (score 1):

First off create a gradient xml file in the drawable folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient android:startColor="#000" android:angle="90"/>
</shape>
```

---

**For API 23 and above:**
In your layout where the ImageView is defined just add the attribute `android:foreground = "@drawable/gradient"`. This simply lays the gradient on top of the ImageView.

---

**Simple but not advised**
You could just add another ImageView ontop of the one which displays the Image. Then the ImageView laid on top would have set the `android:src = "@drawable/gradient"` attribute set. This does work but I would not advise it. Yes it is simple but using ViewOverlay (as we will see in the next solution) is more efficent.

---

**Otherwise**
It's getting a bit more complicated here. First off you must register a ViewTreeObserver with addOnGlobalLayoutListener and implement the method OnGlobalLayout. Then you simply get the gradient drawable and apply the bounds of the ImageView (which will be its parent to it). In the end just set the drawable as ViewOverlay of the ImageView.

Honestly initially I thought it will be enough to write this but I am realizing that it's really complicated. So here is the **ugly** Kotlin version of it:

```
ivImage.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener {
    val drawable = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.gradient).apply {
        bounds = Rect(0, 0, ivImage.width, ivImage.height)
    }
    ivImage.overlay.add(drawable)
}
```

This would be the Java version (also not beautiful code):

```
imageView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.gradient);
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, imageView.getWidth(), imageView.getHeight());
        imageView.getOverlay().add(drawable);
    }
});
```

---

**IMPORTANT: Do not forger to unregister your OnGlobalLayoutListener.**
This can be done in Java inside the onGlobalLayout method like this:                 `imageView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);`

Answer (score 1):

The way you do it is with FrameLayout(Frame Layout helps you to place layouts one over the other). Inside frame Layout first, put ImageView and then a normal View with the background as gradient_transparent_black.xml (So Basically view is above the ImageView).

**Following is an example:** (You can make the View height whatever you want I have it here as 80dp. Also in my example, FrameLayout is inside a ConstraintLayout)

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toOf="@+id/imageView3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/image_you_want" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_transparent_black"
        android:clickable="false" />

</FrameLayout>
```

**gradient_transparent_black.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<gradient
    android:startColor="#000000"
    android:endColor="#00FFFFFF"
    android:angle="90"
    android:dither="true"
    />
</shape>
```

Comment: A relative layout you can place views on top of another again. Okay i will try and get back to you

Comment: I would recommend FrameLayout since its purpose is to place objects one over the other 

You probably know but just as supplementary info : 
The order of elements inside FrameLayout determines the z position, the first element at the bottom and the last element is at the top. Use **gravity** to position elements wrt to parent.

Hope it helps, any doubt feel free to ask in the comments.