# ImageView stretching shadow

Tags: android, imageview, drawable

I would like to draw an imageview with a shadow, but i would like the shadow to stretch. An example.

[image]

```
Is there a way i could extend imageview to draw such shadow? 
Will such shadow follow the shape of the image?
```

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693234/custom-imageview-with-drop-shadow
    Have a look at that.

Comment: Hi Juilousraj, i am not looking for a drop shadow, but something like the image. However i will try out the solutions mentioned in those posts

Comment: sure, you can override `onDraw` and draw whatever you want