# How to add shadow to image programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, svg, graphics, shadow

I have a number of various predefined shapes (geometric, animals, plants, signs, etc.), like the one attached, but without a shadow. Images, containing these shapes, can be saved either as assets or resources.

[image]

Is there a way to add shadow programmatically? If the solution works only for certain image format(s) (bmp, png, svg, etc.) - I can adjust the format as required.

Comment: I personally like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34692779/7034621).

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score -3):

```
android:background="@drawable/shadow"
```

**And shadow.xml would be like**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!--the shadow comes from here-->
<item
    android:bottom="0dp"
    android:drawable="@android:drawable/YOUR_DRAWABLE"
    android:left="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:top="0dp">
</item>
<item
    android:bottom="0dp"
    android:left="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:top="0dp">
    <!--BackGround Color -->
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/red" />

    </shape>
</item>
```

**For More Details You Can See [THIS LINK](https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html)**

Comment: wouldn't it create rectangular shadow around the entire view instead of a shadow around the shape itself?

Comment: @Asahi Do you have limited type of drawables or want it would be dynamically?

Comment: @Asahi If you have certain drawables then you can customize it accordingly. else you have to find the coordinates about which you want to make shadow.

Comment: Number of images is going to change over time (some will be removed, new will be added).

Comment: @Asahi I agree, Once  I was also facing this problem but I had very limited drawables to i could manage only this code.

Answer (score -3):

another way to do it can be adding a elevation to your imageView

```
android:elevation="8dp"
```

Comment: This won't be suitable as per requirement..